# How to Access jQuery Plugin From A Separate Webpack Bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm bundling JS and CSS (compiled from SCSS) into two separate bundles, one for 3rd party (*vendor*) and one for the project code (*company*). I'm able to access jQuery via $ successfully from scripts in the company bundle as a global, such as from *some-other-script.js*, without any issues. However when trying to call the *stickyTableHeaders* function from the [StickyTableHeaders plugin](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) in table-headers.js: *Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stickyTableHeaders is not a function*. I don't get any other errors about loading scripts etc. and I can see that vendor.bundle.js includes the plugin code.

Additionally I see from the bottom of the [plugin source](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js) that the function is meant to be added to $ as follows:

```
$.fn[name] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + name);
        if (instance) {
            if (typeof options === 'string') {
                instance[options].apply(instance);
            } else {
                instance.updateOptions(options);
            }
        } else if(options !== 'destroy') {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + name, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};
```

1. Any ideas why it can't find the function on the $ (jQuery) object?
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) seems similar, however the poster was having trouble with the plugin not being able to find jQuery in that case. Additionally I'm not sure if using the [import-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) as per one of the suggestions is the right approach in my case, or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. You can see commented out lines in the *webpack.config.js* below where I've tried to register *sticky-table-headers* as a plugin with webpack without success - same result.

My *webpack.config.js* is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].bundle.css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = function (env) {

env = env || {};
var isProd = env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// Setup base config for all environments
var config = {
    entry: {
        vendor: './Client/js/vendor',
        company: './Client/js/company'    // Includes all SCSS, which ends up in company.bundle.css via extract-text-webpack-plugin.
    },
    output: {
    // ReSharper disable once UseOfImplicitGlobalInFunctionScope
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            "jquery.validation": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js",
            //"sticky-table-headers": "sticky-table-headers/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            //"sticky-table-headers": ["sticky-table-headers", "default"]
        }),
        extractSass
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSass.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }],
                    // use style-loader in development
                    fallback: "style-loader"
                })
            }
        ]
    }
}

// Alter config for prod environment
if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';  // SourceMap emitted as a separate file. 
    //Normally disallow access on webserver or use (none) instead. Internal 
    //app so leaving them accessible for easier support.
    config.mode = "production";
    }
   return config;
};
```

Then in *vendor.js* I have:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import "jquery-validation";
import "jquery-validation-unobtrusive";
import "sticky-table-headers";
```

In *company.js* I have:

```
import '../scss/site.scss';
import './site';
import './some-other-script';
import './table-headers';
```

Finally in *table-headers.js* I have:

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        if ($(".my-sticky-table-header").length === 0) return;        
        var offset = $('.navbar').height();
        $(".my-sticky-table-header").stickyTableHeaders({ 
fixedOffset:offset});        
    });
})();
```

Thanks.

Comment: If I install import-loader and change the last line of *vendor.js* to (yuck):

    import exec from 'script-loader!../../node_modules/sticky-table- 
   headers/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js';

Then I get this error:

webpack-internal:///./node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js:8 [Script Loader] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (eval at module.exports (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js), ...
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/script-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sticky-table-headers/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js:1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a fundamental flaw with this setup. I ended up adding:

```
import './vendor';
```

to the top of *company.js* and then using the *SplitChunks* plugin mentioned [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to avoid everything in the *vendor* bundle being duplicated. This allowed library functions to be called from the *company* bundle.

(Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724565/expose-javascript-globals-bundled-via-webpack) may have worked but it seems messy).

Comment: FYI: That seemed to break the Bootstrap 4 drop-down menu, which relies on popper.js. No errors, just didn't do anything. Other Bootstrap functionality still working. Have decided to move to a single bundle now after struggling with this.